# How to make Alt + Click work with Gnome panel in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I am using 12.04 with Gnome 3.

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right Click</kbd> works in Gnome Classic. However, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> doesn't work with Gnome Panel.

Normally, it should bring up a way to customize the panel.

Comment: Could you update your question to include what you think should happen?  It would also be helpful to know which destkop mode you're running in: Unity, Unity 2D, GNOME, GNOME Fallback, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the problem, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-panel/+bug/891622

We need to run the following command in terminal:

```
gconftool-2 --set --type string /apps/metacity/general/mouse_button_modifier '<Super>'
```